# haproxy pass origin IP in galera cluster db

Tags: mariadb, haproxy

We have one galera cluster, mariadb version 10.3 and haproxy.

We want the users to connect like this client->haproxy->galera_cluster.
The user we create in the database we allow the IP to the client. 
For http we found that you can use send-proxy or X-Origin IP in the header.

We want to, to the same with galera cluster, TCP protocol.

We add this in mariadb config file: "proxy_protocol_networks     = haproxy_server/32"

We use ubuntu 16.04 and haproxy 1.6.

haproxy config file

```
 backend galera
 bind 0.0.0.0:3306
 balance leastconn
 mode tcp
 option tcpka
 option forwardfor
 option log-health-checks
 retries                   3
 timeout queue             1m
 timeout connect           15s
 timeout client            50m
 timeout server            50m
 timeout check             10s
 option mysql-check user haproxy
 server node1 IP_Cluster_1:3306 check send-proxy
```

Any ideas how we can to that.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it was in the haproxy config file.
This is the correct config file of haproxy.

```
frontend mysqld_listen
    bind *:3306
    mode tcp
    log global
    option  dontlognull
    option tcplog
    use_backend galera

backend galera
    balance leastconn
    mode tcp
    option tcpka
    option tcplog
    option log-health-checks
    retries                   3
    option mysql-check user haproxy
    server node1 IP_1:3306 check weight 1 send-proxy-v2
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB supports the Proxy Protocol beginning in 10.3, so `send-proxy` should work.

But first, you need to configure `proxy-protocol-networks` with the subnet of the proxy (not of the clients).

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/proxy-protocol-support/

Comment: Hello, 

Thanks for the reply.

In the my.cnf we have the configure of the IP proxy server.
For the haproxy config we try the send-proxy and send-proxy-v2  , nothing happens.
We can telnet the port but when we try to connect, it asks us for the password but not any reply. Also not error. I add now the haproxy config file